# Schengen visa flexibility

Tags: visas, schengen, international-travel

I'm travelling to Denmark in June for 2 weeks and have already got my Schengen visa from the Denmark consulate.

After entering Denmark , if I decide to spend 1.5 weeks of my trip in Greece now, is that still an option? I know the general practice is that you should apply for the visa from the Schengen country you spend the most time in but what happens if this changes mid-trip?

From what I remember, there is no passport control when you move within the Schengen so can they even find out where you spend most of your time?

Comment: Note that due to the migrant crisis, there are actually many more passport controls between Schengen countries than there are supposed to be. I wouldn't be surprised if you were controlled on your way from Greece to Denmark. Not so much the other way around. What's your new itinerary?

Answer (score 2):

**In principle,** a Schengen visa whith "Schengen States" (or the equivalent in the national language) allows you to visit **any** Schengen state.

You can adjust your itinerary during the trip, even visiting states that were not on your itinerary. However, you may not misrepresent your travel plans to get that visa. It is up to you to avoid this impression, because the problem will be yours and not the immigration officers'.

So **in practice** you can adjust your trip if the main purpose is clearly the same, and if you can document that. Perhaps you arrive in Amsterdam instead of Frankfurt because you found a cheaper flight. Or you planned to drive a car from Copenhagen to Rome and you decide to drive through Switzerland instead of Austria. (It helps if you have documentation for your entire trip with you, should that be challenged.)

If you are already in the Schengen area, and you manage to travel without a paper trail, of course you can cheat the system. But if Schengen authorities suspect that you do that, you might have a hard time getting your next visa.